# How to hide x and y axis line only in highchart?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am integrating highchart using angularJs, I want to hide x and y axis line only, I tried with **lineColor: 'transparent'**, it working for line chart only, not working for bar/column chart,

I attached screenshots of issue here for more understanding,

[image: In this image in x and y axis line not showing.]

[image: But same configuration not working for column chart.]

can any one please guide me for the same.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For column and bar charts, even if you make the line color of the x-axis transparent, you'll still see the grid line for your minimum y-axis value, which is "0" in your chart.

Here's how you can change this:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'], 
    /* make the x-axis line invisible */
    lineColor: 'transparent'
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    },
    /* make all y-axis gridlines invisible */
    gridLineColor: 'transparent'
},
```

Here's a fiddle that shows this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/13z2kLcf/

One question: in your second screenshot, it looks like you may have already made your y-axis grid lines transparent. Is that true? If so, it would be helpful to see your code to understand why you'd still have that blue line below your columns. I'll be happy to amend my answer if what I shared above doesn't work out.

Comment: Thanks @Mike for your time, Yes you are right I already made y-axis grid line transparent, but there is a  mistake I also set plotLines,
`yAxis: {title: {
                                text: 'Values'
                            },
                            gridLineWidth: 0,
                            gridLineColor: 'transparent',
plotLines: [{
                                    value: 0,
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: '#437ede'
                                }]
}`
, so that is why there is blue line displayed.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! One thing I had thought about was, if you wanted to keep the grid lines for your y-axis *except* the one at the bottom, you could use a plot line, but color it white instead ... that way, it would overlap the bottom grid line and still avoid a line under your columns.

Comment: Yes that is right, thanks again Mike for this solution.

Comment: One more thing, Is it possible if I want to start Column from Left most corner of X-Axis? Like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/13z2kLcf/) fiddle it should start from first tick of x axis.

Comment: @GauravRadadiya So you want the first column to be up against the axis, rather than centered between the axis and the first tick mark on your y-axis?

Comment: yes exactly, Can you please update that thing in given fiddle?

Comment: @GauravRadadiya I'd suggest you ask a new, separate question for this requirement, since that wasn't part of your original post. That way, it'll be clearer for those who find and read this specific question. Point me to the new question, and I'll see whether what you're asking is possible. Thank you!

Comment: @Mark , Sure I will post a new Question for this. Thank you